# Dynamic setting of jnlp codebase attribute

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jnlp

In my `JSP`, I jave a `jnlp` tag:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="%{jnlpCodebase}" >
```

In the action class, I do have a `public String getJnlpCodebase()`. The method never gets invoked (I know because I debug) which other JSP variable methods from the `struts` action do (but are not in the jnlp tag itself).

Is there something that prevents the jnlp tag from using action methods to set this (or other) values dynamically? How do I enable a dynamic generation of the jnlp codebase? I need it because the URL in the codebase varies by environment and I can't hardcode it.

Answer (score 1):

User Struts property tag like below

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="<s:property value="jnlpCodebase" />" >
```